# Generic constraint inference in class signature

Tags: c#, .net, generic-constraints

I am frustrated by certain requirements when working with C# generic constraints, and I'd like to know if there is a way around my issues.  If not, I'd like an explanation for why things don't work the way I'd like them to.

This example shows what I basically have to do currently:

```
public abstract class EntityBase<TID>
    where TID : struct, IEquatable<TID>
{ }

public abstract class LogicBase<TEntity, TID>
    where TEntity : EntityBase<TID>
    where TID : struct, IEquatable<TID>
{ }

public abstract class ServiceBase<TLogic, TEntity, TID>
    where TLogic : LogicBase<TEntity, TID>
    where TEntity : EntityBase<TID>
    where TID : struct, IEquatable<TID>
{ }

// Concrete Examples
public class EgEntity : EntityBase<long> {}
public class EgLogic : LogicBase<EgEntity, long> {}
public class EgService : ServiceBase<EgLogic, EgEntity, long> {}
```

**Proposal A** shows what I wish was available (and I see no reason why it couldn't work this way):

```
public abstract class EntityBase<TID>
    where TID : struct, IEquatable<TID>
{ }

public abstract class LogicBase<TEntity>
    where TEntity : EntityBase<?>  // why not allow some kind of a "this could be whatever" syntax here ("?"), then infer the constraints on "?" based on the definition of EntityBase<>
{ }

public abstract class ServiceBase<TLogic>
    where TLogic : LogicBase<?>  // infer the constraints on "?" based on the definition of LogicBase<>
{ }

// Concrete Examples
public class EgEntity : EntityBase<long> {}
public class EgLogic : LogicBase<EgEntity> {}
public class EgService : ServiceBase<EgLogic> {}
```

**Proposal B** shows another possible alternative, though not as attractive as Proposal A:

```
public abstract class EntityBase<TID>
    where TID : struct, IEquatable<TID>
{ }

public abstract class LogicBase<TEntity>
    where TEntity : EntityBase<TID>  // introduce TID here to keep it out of class signature
    where TID : struct, IEquatable<TID>
{ }

public abstract class ServiceBase<TLogic>
    where TLogic : LogicBase<TEntity>  // introduce TEntity here
    where TEntity : EntityBase<TID>  // introduce TID here
    where TID : struct, IEquatable<TID>
{ }

// Concrete Examples
public class EgEntity : EntityBase<long> {}
public class EgLogic : LogicBase<EgEntity> {}
public class EgService : ServiceBase<EgLogic> {}
```

Both proposals would minimize the number of type parameters I have to specify when creating derived types, and Proposal A would eliminate the need for a bunch of redundant constraints.

So is there a reason that C# couldn't/shouldn't provide support for one of these proposals?  (Or by some chance have I overlooked a relevant existing feature of the language?)

Comment: Eric Lippert's [Why not automatically infer constraints](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/03/09/why-not-automatically-infer-constraints.aspx) post

Comment: I knew I'd read something similar previously - while Eric's scenario doesn't 100% line up with the question, the reasoning he gives maps pretty well across.

Comment: Eric Lippert's article was fantastic and exactly what I needed to read, although I'm not sure it fully addressed Proposal B.

Answer (score 2):

That's the way C# is basically. There is some limitations of where in terms of what restrictions it will let you put on types.

Generally speaking most of the options for the `where` clause relates to things where adding this restriction will allow you to do something with the object inside your generic class which is dependant upon the generic type used (EG: By telling it `TID` is an `IEquatable<TID>`, you can use TID as though it is an IEquatable later). The logic being that if you're not depending on that functionality in any way then there's no reason practically that your class needs the restriction (Though I admit it can be nice for the sake of cleanness).

When it comes to the desired `LogicBase<?>`, a very complicated puzzle has been raised as far as exactly what you can now do with this object. When you have a `ServiceBase<TLogic>` with your TLogic defined as  `LogicBase<?>` in it, what functionality of LogicBase is actually possible to use?

If you're looking to get some subset of the functionality that doesn't depend on knowing it's generic type, then what I would say is really you need to define an `Interface` or even just an `abstract class` defining the functionality of the `ServiceBase<TLogic>` which is not dependant on the data type `TLogic` and restrain your `ServiceBase<TLogic>`'s `TLogic` to be of this new type. Because that's realistically what you're asking the application to infer for you (An interface which represents the components of a `LogicBase<?>` which are not inherently dependant on it's generic type).

So while in theory the compiler could interpret this in this way & work out a desired enforcement of the constraint and available interface to the object without reference to it's data type, it adds a significant overhead in terms of the complexity of the inheritance setup and my personal thoughts would be that simply declaring an interface would be a more structured way to deal with the issue.

Comment: I couldn't have explained it better.

Comment: My point was that the compiler could reasonably already know the constraints for the ? in LogicBase<?> by looking at the signature of LogicBase<TEntity> itself.  It's not that ? would mean there is NO constraint on the type parameter, just that any constraints should be inferred from the containing generic type.  Basically, why put the exact same constraint in two places when the compiler could reasonably infer it?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you define an interface IEntityBase and make LogicBase and ServiceBase dependent on this interface only. This would enable you to get rid of the TEntity type parameter.

Comment: In my specific situation, an interface does not get me what I need.  I truly want generics, as I want to be dealing with the actual types in the base classes.  Could be I don't fully understand your suggestion, though.